# Python 3 How to change a class 'str' to class 'int'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using qpython3. The class not changed by `int()`. Here is sample code in qpython3 console.

```
>>> a = "8"
>>> a
'8'
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>
>>> int(a)
8
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>
```

The class remain string. Following assign int to a variable as contrast:

```
>>> a = 8
>>> a
8
>>> type(a)
<class 'int'>
```

The issue here is if taking an `int` character from  `input()`, further mathematical operation and logic comparison are prohibited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you didnt assign it, try this

```
a = int(a)
```

when you say int(a) it returns an integer value, and the interpeter prints it, but you have to assign it to a

```
>>> a = "3"
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>
>>> a = int(a)
>>> a
3
>>> type(a)
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: int([number | string[, base]])
Convert a number or string to an integer.
Mislead by the python doc. It return an int object instead of convert it.

Answer (score 0):

In python, strings and integers are immutable. i.e, calling a function on it will not change its structure in place.

This means you have to return whatever the function returns to another variable.

```
>>> a = '8'
>>> print(type(a))
<class 'str'>
>>> a = int(a) # a = int('8')
>>> print(type(a))
<class 'int'>
```

Notice how we override the variable `a` with the integer.